# Proving $x\ln(\frac{x}{a})+y\ln(\frac{y}{b})\geq (x+y)\ln(\frac{x+y}{a+b})$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, convex-analysis

> Let a,b,x,y be positive reals. Prove $x\ln(\frac{x}{a})+y\ln(\frac{y}{b})\geq (x+y)\ln(\frac{x+y}{a+b})$

I don't have any olympic background, so I may be missing some standard trick.

The inequality looks closely related to the concavity of $\ln$.

**EDIT**: the following is wrong as stated by Macavity.

Indeed using points $\frac{x}{a}$,$\frac{y}{b}$, and $\frac{x}{x+y}$,$\frac{y}{x+y}$ as weights, one has $$\frac{x}{x+y}\ln(\frac{x}{a})+\frac{y}{x+y}\ln(\frac{y}{b})\geq \ln(\frac{x^2}{x+y}\frac{1}{a}+\frac{y^2}{x+y}\frac{1}{b})$$

But I can't prove that $\displaystyle\frac{x^2}{x+y}\frac{1}{a}+\frac{y^2}{x+y}\frac{1}{b}\geq \frac{x+y}{a+b}$

Comment: Concavity would mean your first inequality is reversed, wouldn't it? So you don't need the Cauchy Schwarz part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@math110  is right, but you have started with the wrong inequality.  You can use concavity instead directly and get:
$$\frac{x}{x+y}\ln \left(\frac{a}x \right)+\frac{y}{x+y}\ln \left(\frac{b}y \right) \le \ln\left(\frac{a+b}{x+y} \right)$$

Now multiplying throughout by $-1$ (which flips the fractions in parentheses) gets you what you want.

Comment: Yes that's embarassing :P Thanks for noticing my blatant mistake.

Answer (score 4):

use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have
$$\left(\dfrac{x^2}{a}+\dfrac{y^2}{b}\right)(a+b)\ge (x+y)^2$$